# Remove duplicates by date in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list of objects order by date. Each object have the folling structure

```js
export class SegmentDTO  {
  dateInsert: Date;
  dateModified: Date;
  id: number;
  language: number;
  content: string;
}
```

I want to get the disctincs object based on `language` property, and take the most recent one of each language (based on `dateModified`)

What I tried is this:

```js
const listLangOrderByDateASC = this.segments.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.dateInsert).getTime() - new Date(b.dateInsert).getTime());

 const result = [...new Map(listSourceLangOrderByDateASC.map(item => [item.language, item])).values()];
```

With this, I can obtain the most recent object for each language, but I don't know if there is a better approach to do it. I discover that making this takes the final objects of the sorted list, but I don't really know if it's just lucky.

Any help would be aprecciated!

Comment: have you tried lodash? they have some functions for getting distinct objects and they are performant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the most recently modified items, grouped by language.

We'll create an object, with a key for each language. If the object has no value at the language key *or* the value has an older modified date, we'll replace with the new entry.

Once we've grouped the items, we'll convert to an array again with `Object.values()`

```js
let segments = [ { dateInsert: new Date('2022-06-01T07:00:00Z'), dateModified: new Date('2022-06-02T09:00:00Z'), id: 1, language: 1, content: 'Content', }, { dateInsert: new Date('2022-06-01T07:00:00Z'), dateModified: new Date('2022-06-02T11:00:00Z'), id: 1, language: 1, content: 'Content', }, { dateInsert: new Date('2022-06-01T07:00:00Z'), dateModified: new Date('2022-06-02T14:00:00Z'), id: 1, language: 2, content: 'Content', }, { dateInsert: new Date('2022-06-01T07:00:00Z'), dateModified: new Date('2022-06-01T19:00:00Z'), id: 1, language: 2, content: 'Content', } ];

const result = Object.values(segments.reduce((acc, obj) => { 
    if (!acc[obj.language] || (acc[obj.language].dateModified < obj.dateModified)) {
        acc[obj.language] = obj;
    }
    return acc;
}, {}));
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

We can also do this with a `Map` object:

```js
const segments = [ { dateInsert: new Date('2022-06-01T07:00:00Z'), dateModified: new Date('2022-06-02T09:00:00Z'), id: 1, language: 1, content: 'Content', }, { dateInsert: new Date('2022-06-01T07:00:00Z'), dateModified: new Date('2022-06-02T11:00:00Z'), id: 1, language: 1, content: 'Content', }, { dateInsert: new Date('2022-06-01T07:00:00Z'), dateModified: new Date('2022-06-02T14:00:00Z'), id: 1, language: 2, content: 'Content', }, { dateInsert: new Date('2022-06-01T07:00:00Z'), dateModified: new Date('2022-06-01T19:00:00Z'), id: 1, language: 2, content: 'Content', } ];

const result = [...segments.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    if ((!acc.has(obj.language) || (acc.get(obj.language).dateModified) < obj.dateModified)) {
        acc.set(obj.language, obj);
    }
    return acc;
}, new Map()).values()];
console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This looks more robust than my code. I've tried it and it works very good. I didn't know this way. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```js
const segments = [{
 dateInsert: new Date('2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
 dateModified: new Date('2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
 id: 1,
 language: 1,
 content: 'My content'
},{
 dateInsert: new Date('2022-01-01 00:00:00'),
 dateModified: new Date('2022-01-02 00:00:00'),
 id: 2,
 language: 1,
 content: 'My content'
}
]


const mostRecentByLanguage = Object.values(segments.reduce((res, item) => {
  
  const existing =  res[item.language] || {dateModified :new Date('1970-01-01 00:00:00')}

  return {
    ...res,
    [item.language]: item.dateModified.getTime() > existing.dateModified.getTime() ?item:existing
  }

}, {})).flat()

console.log(mostRecentByLanguage)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can browse all  table elements and slice the table from current index+1 until the  last element, if you don't find the current element you push it in a new table:

```
var unique =[]
arr.forEach((e,i,s)=>{
if(s.slice(i+1).filter(c=>c.language==e.language).length==0)
unique.push(e)
})
```